# Adding onmouseover to display titles on php outputed game tumbnails

Tags: php, css, onmouseover

Here i tried to style the default title tooltip with this code, but cant seem to make the images respond to the mouseover for a styled tooltip that should show as a game title?

```
[data-title]:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.1s ease 0.5s;
  visibility: visible;
}
[data-title]:after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  background-color: #00FF00;
  color: #111;
  font-size: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1px 5px 2px 5px;
  bottom: -1.6em;
  left: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222222;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid #111111;
  z-index: 99999;
  visibility: hidden;
}
[data-title] {
  position: relative;
}
```

the php:

```
echo '<div class="ran_box">';
echo '<a href="' . $siteurl . 'index.php?act=game&id=' . $games['id'] . '">';
echo '<img src="' . $thumbnail . '" width="60" height="60" data-title="'. $games['title'] . '"></a></div>';
```

Comment: Any thoughts out there? i would like to maybe try a inline javascript, tried wrapping it in a span and div but no luck.

Comment: This line forces a browser mouseover showing title and description but cant be styled.   echo '<img src="' . $thumbnail . '" width="60" height="60" title="'.$games['title'].$games['description'].'"></a></div>';

Comment: Here i tried to style the default title tooltip with this code, but cant seem to make the images respond to the mouseover for a styled tooltip that should show as a game title?

Comment: Well i got it, by combining div class="ran_box" with the tool tip css i was able to create a nice styled tool tip that shows the game titles, If anyone cares to see the results it can be  found on the game play page of my site https://www.funplaytyme.com/